# Show image if div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to show an image when a div is clicked.

The first one is working but the second one isn't.

What I've tried so far, but it didn't work:

```js
$('#review').click(function() {
  var src = $('#review').attr('src');
  $('#result').attr('src', src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="review" src="http://web-images.chacha.com/aardvark/aardvark-may-9-2011-200.jpg" class="background-markup-center skew-15deg ro-buttons">
<p class="noskew-15deg text-center">John Doe</p>
</div>

<div id="review" src="http://web-images.chacha.com/aardvark/aardvark-may-9-2011-200.jpg" class="background-markup-center skew-15deg ro-buttons">
<p class="noskew-15deg text-center">Doe John</p>
</div>

<img id="result" />
```

Comment: Don't use two or more same identificators on one page! The `id` attribute should be **unique**. See [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.review').click(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $('#result').attr('src', src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="review" src="http://web-images.chacha.com/aardvark/aardvark-may-9-2011-200.jpg" class="background-markup-center skew-15deg ro-buttons">
<p class="noskew-15deg text-center">John Doe</p>
</div>

<div class="review" src="ad">
<p class="noskew-15deg text-center">Doe John</p>
</div>

<img id="result" />
```

1. Use class Id should be unique
2. use this context to refer to click element

Answer (score 2):

> id = name [CS] This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name
>   must be unique in a document.

You  have used `id="review"` for two elements. It is not possible.

Used `this` selector in the function. Otherwise the first element with the class will be used.

```js
$('.review').click(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $('#result').attr('src', src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="review" src="http://web-images.chacha.com/aardvark/aardvark-may-9-2011-200.jpg" class="background-markup-center skew-15deg ro-buttons">
  <p class="noskew-15deg text-center">John Doe</p>
</div>

<div class="review" src="http://web-images.chacha.com/aardvark/aardvark-may-9-2011-200.jpg" class="background-markup-center skew-15deg ro-buttons">
  <p class="noskew-15deg text-center">Doe John</p>
</div>

<img id="result" />
```

Answer (score 0):

An `Id` should be unique, use class to select by in this case

```js
$('.review').click(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $('#result').attr('src', src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div src="http://web-images.chacha.com/aardvark/aardvark-may-9-2011-200.jpg" class="background-markup-center review skew-15deg ro-buttons">
<p class="noskew-15deg text-center">John Doe</p>
</div>

<div src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg" class="background-markup-center review skew-15deg ro-buttons">
<p class="noskew-15deg text-center">Doe John</p>
</div>

<img id="result" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique, but by any reason if you can't change it,then you can use attribute selector like below as id selector returns first matching element!

```js
$("[id='review']").click(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $('#result').attr('src', src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="review" src="http://web-images.chacha.com/aardvark/aardvark-may-9-2011-200.jpg" class="background-markup-center skew-15deg ro-buttons">
<p class="noskew-15deg text-center">John Doe</p>
</div>

<div id="review" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Small-world-network-example.png/220px-Small-world-network-example.png" class="background-markup-center skew-15deg ro-buttons">
<p class="noskew-15deg text-center">Doe John</p>
</div>

<img id="result" />
```